# problem arising while installing pandas library in python

Tags: python, pandas

i am installing pandas for python on windows 10.

this is the code i am typing in cmd:

```
pip install pandas
```

normally this should have led to the installation of pandas. however, i am getting the following error in cmd:

C:>pip install pandas
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i have installed anaconda before.

Answer (score 0):

I would first guess that pip is not installed. Which version of Python are you using? Is python set in your path correctly?

If python 3, pip should be installed, not always the case with python 2. You can use this
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. This should set you straight.

Comment: i am using python 3.7

Comment: what happens when you just type python and hit enter at the command prompt?

Comment: the python interactive shell opens

Answer (score 0):

OS : Widwos
Follow the link "https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/" to install pip